# RDS export log files

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I want to export error log , general log and slow-query log from RDS Mysql.
I am done with all the necessary settings on my DB Instance.
I have exported the general log and slow-query log to file. (log_output : FILE)

What is the best approach to do this.

I am thinking to use lambda for this. But I am not able to find a suitable way to trigger my lambda function, eg : When ever a new log file is created my lambda function must be triggered.

Is it possible to push this log files events to CloudWatch directly ?
I have gone through the documentation , but I am not able to find such mechanism.

How should I proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no Supported Event Source for RDS in Lambda. I would suggest using a table to store logs for each kind in the parameters. And call the rotation to remove the old data to save disk space.